# The VM with Kali Linux hangs

Tags: linux, vmware, kali-linux

I have downloaded the newest Back Track version *"Kali Linux"* as a [VM image](http://www.kali.org/downloads/).

I run it using my VM Workstation latest build. First time I visited Youtube to play some videos it asked me to download Adobe but when I use the Virtual machine to work on the installation of Adobe it hangs and I can't use it.

Someone has told me before it's a VM side issue thus now I got my latest build of the VM but nothing has changed.

Can somebody suggest me why that is?

Comment: What exactly hangs?

Comment: @HaukeLaging the VM workstation I guess freezes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was with the amount of RAM dedicated to the VM machine of the guest I have now dedicated have of my original RAM to the VM machine and it's running perfectly..

Comment: Could you explain it? I do not understand your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I gave it one more shot and it worked here is what I did. I changed the install comparability to v 11x not 12v for VMware. However I dont think that was the resolution. Then I set  1CPU with 4 Core and 2048 for RAM when I installed I chose that I will install an OS later and I selected Dabian 7 x 64. Once again I dont think that is the the root cause.

HERE IT IS... when you install it asks about the GRUB Boot Loader. It defaults to the "Enter the device manually"

Select the other option "/dev/sda"

I think that is the fix. I will follow through to see if I can narrow it down. 
Enjoy kids

Comment: 100% it is in the setup  option "/dev/sda"